# /etc/vsftpd/_vsftpd.conf: binary operator expected on Red Hat

Tags: linux, ftp, redhat, vsftpd

I'm running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga). Eerytime I try to start the vsftpd service, I recieved this error

```
[root@localhost ~]# service vsftpd start
/etc/init.d/vsftpd: line 40: [: /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf: binary operator expected

Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                                [FAILED]
```

Here is my vsftpd.config file

```
    # Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
    anonymous_enable=YES
    #
    # Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
    local_enable=YES
    #
    # Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
    #write_enable=YES
    #
    # Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
    # if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
    #local_umask=022
    #
    # Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
    # has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
    # obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
    #anon_upload_enable=YES
    #
    # Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
    # new directories.
    #anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
    #
    # Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
# 
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
# 
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
# 
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
# 
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
# 
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
xferlog_std_format=YES
# 
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.

# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
# 
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
# 
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
# 
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_local_user=YES
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
# 
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
# 
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and   
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
#listen=YES
# 
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
#listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

convert_charset_enable=1
local_charset=UTF8
remote_charset=WIN1251
double_377=0

#pasv_addr_rules=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pasv_rules


anti_bruteforce=1
anti_bruteforce_banner=Bruteforce detected. Server in safe mode.

http_enable=no
ftp_enable=yes
http_browse=no

http_browse_tpl=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-browse.html
http_browse_line_tpl=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-browse_line.html
http_error_403_server_tpl=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-403-serv.html
http_error_403_tpl=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-403.html
http_error_404_tpl=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-404.html

one_process_model=yes
```

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you asked a server configuration question on a site about programming languages.

Comment: I disagree a little bit, his error is script-language error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work for me I change line 124 of the .conf-file to

```
anti_bruteforce_banner="Bruteforce detected. Server in safe mode."
```

(added the ").